# Optimise memory usage with plt.imread()

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, matplotlib

I am working with a lot of images (120k), each image is a component of RGB + yellow of a single image (so I have 30k unique images all break down in 4 images: one for Red, Green, Blue and Yellow)

For each image ID, I merge the 4 components (RGB + yellow) into a (M,N,4) array (where M and N are the dimensions of the image).

I work with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from os import listdir

train_labels_data = pd.read_csv('/Documents/train.csv')

def merge_rgb(img_id, colours=['red','blue','green','yellow'], path = 'train'):

"""
For each images, returns an array of shape (M,N,4) 
where each dimension in the 4 are red, blue, green and yellow.
"""
    merged_colour_img = []

    for colour in colours:
        full_path = path + '/' + img_id + '_' + colour + '.png'
        colour_img=mpimg.imread(full_path)
        merged_colour_img.append(colour_img)    

    merged_colour_img = np.dstack((merged_colour_img))
    return merged_colour_img


def train_data_label(train_labels_data):

"""
From the train_labels csv file, create a list of labels, and create a large 
array for the train data in same order.
"""
    train_ids = [img_id for img_id in train_labels_data['Id']]
    train_labels = [label for label in train_labels_data['Target']]

    print ('Labels and Ids collected')

    train_data = []

    i=0
    for img_id in train_ids:

        print ('Merging Image')
        train_data_img = merge_rgb (img_id)
        print ('Merging done, appending the (M,N,4) array to a list')
        train_data.append(train_data_img)
        i += 1
        print ('Done appending, going to next image')
        print(i)

    print('Stacking all images in one big array')
    train_data = np.stack(train_data)

    return train_labels, train_data


train_labels, train_data = train_data_label(train_labels_data)


# SAVE OUTPUT

data_pickle_train = pickle.dumps(train_data)
data = open("/Documents/train_data.pkl","wb")
data.write(data_pickle_train)
data.close()

data_pickle_train_labels = pickle.dumps(train_labels)
data = open("/Documents/train_data_labels.pkl","wb")
data.write(data_pickle_train_labels)
data.close()
```

However this code uses a lot of memory and crashes half way before all images are processed. Since I am working with images I suspect I could improve the merge_rgb function, any advice how to?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you expect? A final array consisting of 120k images of this type with, let's say, 256x256 pixels will be somewhat 30Gb. Numpy's internals (doubling internal memory allocation when appending over current limit; **edit** irrelevant as you use lists, which is good) can make this worse. Don't use pickle and co. Do that image-per-image and store this dynamically into something with random-access like behaviour (hdf5, sql, ...), meaning: not all processed images are in RAM at the same time. Especially for hdf5, you still have numpy-like access behaviour for later stages of your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @sascha, used a hdf5 file as you advised